# How to I extract a date from the following Python string '2021-05-16T13:24:31+0000'?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following date string which I tried to extract the date from. I am getting an error as I am obviously not parsing it correctly.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '2021-05-16T13:24:31+0000'
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S'+0000'"
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
print(date_object.date)
```

What would be the correct parsing format for this date string '2021-05-16T13:24:31+0000'?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote? I haven't found an answer to this precise question on the site. And the question is very clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Those single quotes are messing with the date format, without them the code works fine:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '2021-05-16T13:24:31+0000'
date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000'
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)

print(date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: while that works, it ignores the fact that "+0000" indicates UTC - simply use `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"`.